# display the most frequent value for _several_ columns in a pivot like table?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

How do I display the most frequent value for *several* columns in a pivot like table?

I want the table to mimic the one on page 43 in this [report](https://www.foreignlaborcert.doleta.gov/pdf/OFLC_Annual_Report_FY2016.pdf). 
In other words: I want to get a table of the top 10 employers, showing the following table:

---

**Employer;  Certified positions;  % of certified positions;  Top work state for that employer;  Top occupation for that employer.**

Deloitte; 163000; 14%;  Pennsylvania;  Computer Systems analysts

Price water; 54000; 5%;  California;  Accountants

---

(Sorry the markdown table did not format as it should).

This is a [split/apply/combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) type of action.

I try doing the above with the following code:

```
# select the cols in the table 
cols = ['employer_name', 'case_status', 'worksite_state', 'soc_name']
# decide which aggregation function each col shoudl have in the table 
agg_dict = {'employer_name':'count', 'case_status':'most_frequent', 
                  'worksite_state':'most_frequent', 'soc_name':'most_frequent'}
# select rows the case_status is certified
rows = df.case_status == CERTIFIED
# print out the table 
df[rows].groupby('employer_name')[cols].agg(agg_dict).sort_values(by='employer_name').head(10)
```

Below is the first row of the dataset.

`index                                                   352027
case_number                                 I-200-14111-816263
case_status                                          CERTIFIED
case_submitted                             2014-04-21 16:49:19
decision_date                              2014-04-25 22:00:47
employer_city                                     PHILADELPHIA
employer_name                          DELOITTE CONSULTING LLP
employer_postal_code                                     19103
employment_end_date                        2017-04-22 00:00:00
employment_start_date                      2014-04-22 00:00:00
full_time_position                                           Y
job_title                                    SENIOR CONSULTANT
naic_code                                                54161
prevailing_wage                                         110094
pw_source_other                        OFLC ONLINE DATA CENTER
pw_source_year                                            2013
pw_unit_of_pay                                            Year
pw_wage_source                                             OES
soc_code                                               15-1133
soc_name                 Software Developers, Systems Software
total_workers                                                1
visa_class                                                H-1B
wage_rate_of_pay_from                                   115800
wage_rate_of_pay_to                                        NaN
wage_unit_of_pay                                          Year
worksite_city                                         SAN JOSE
worksite_state                                      California`

Comment: what denotes "top 10"? Also - please print `df.head(5)` and add it here. it seems like what you gave us is all the column names and their first value. It will also help if you only give us the columns that are necessary to provide the desired result.

Comment: "top 10" refers to the 10 most frequent employers. In other words: `df.groupby('employer_name').size().head(10)`